# A system simulator that allows for verilog modifications?

Tags: verilog, simulation

My current research is on hardware security against software attacks, thus I wanted to run some sample C code attacks using a simulator. Do x86-64 simulators (i.e. Marssx86 or QEMU) allow for the user to modify the architecture by adding verilog code? Is there an x86 simulator (either 64 or 32 bits) which creates a processor using verilog?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt any simulator goes anywhere near that low level. All simulators like QEMU do is translate instructions from a virtual environment to be run on the host processor. If you are "emulating" (I use that term loosely) one architecture on another (e.g. one of the many ARM sets on an i386), the simulator doesn't care about how an ARM processor would execute, it only cares what the expected result from each instruction might be.

Processors do a lot to get the intended result from each instruction, and modern processors have complexity in terms of instruction pipelines, branch prediction, caching, parallel processing, and so on. None of these are necessary to get the intended result in a simulator as they are designed for performance.

Nobody would invest the time (especially for free software) to design for example an x86 processor from scratch in Verilog and then run simulations at the hardware level. Aside from anything such a simulation would take an eternity to run - mere nanoseconds would take minutes to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

These sort of simulators work at a high level of abstraction.  That's the only way to get any reasonable level of performance.  They do not use verilog internally nor is there a way to connect a verilog simulation to a software simulation in this way.

What I would recommend doing is finding an open source architecture that you can play with.  x86 is horrendously complex, so something simpler like perhaps RISC-V would be a better idea.  In that case, you can have the whole processor as HDL (maybe verilog, maybe VHDL, maybe some new-fangled higher level language that generates Verilog/VHDL) and you can make all the changes you like and even drop it on to an FPGA and run it in real time.

Answer (score 0):

> Do x86-64 simulators (i.e. Marssx86 or QEMU) allow for the user to modify the architecture by adding verilog code?

No, absolutely not.

QEMU operates at the instruction level. It does not emulate the microarchitecture of the processor at all.

Marss86 does emulate the microarchitecture of an Intel x86 processor, but only at a relatively high level. It primarily focuses on simulating the timing of instructions (e.g, cache and pipelining behavior); instruction execution is handled by QEMU. In essence, it's simulating the *effects* that the microarchitecture has on timing, not the nitty-gritty details of how that microarchitecture is actually implemented.

> Is there an x86 simulator (either 64 or 32 bits) which creates a processor using verilog?

None that I'm aware of, and it's unlikely that one exists outside of x86 licensees, as the code would infringe upon a number of critical patents held by Intel and AMD.

Reading between the lines a bit: If you want a modern, simulatable / synthesizable CPU implemented in an HDL, take a look at RISC-V.